# Firebase simple REST DELETE?

Tags: angularjs, rest, firebase

My data in firebase looks like the below. I am reading https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/ and its weird, I am trying to remove an item.

```
burning-*

contacts  

     -K7qAf6egBeg5l3e_Gjc
       name: "Ind"
       phonenumber: "(408) ***-***"
       uid: "1"

     -K7qB8Afu7bIm9LUtV68
       name: "Paul Bhayya"
       phonenumber: "(408) ***-***"
       uid:"2"
```

Inside angular.js I am making this call inside a custom directive of mine.

```
$http.delete(Firebaseurl + '/contacts/'+scope.contact.name+'/.json').then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The api is not making sense to me, I see the problem might be that my data is now nested inside a key with a weird ID i.e `-K7qAf6egBeg5l3e_Gjc`.

So I am wondering how can I make a call to delete an item by the key `name` so if client side that contact is clicked say `Ind` gets clicked then I tell Firebase to delete the contact with that name. Maybe ID is better, but whatever works.

EDIT:

FYI I parsed the Firebase object `selectedContacts` is the result of the GET method for the objects. It wasnt formatted very well for my angular code so I turned it into a clean array of objects and I am using it to compare to other set of data to pass into the `$scope`

```
Object.keys(selectedContacts.data).forEach(function(key) {
  selectedContactsArray.push(selectedContacts.data[key]);
});

selectedContactsArray.filter( function( item ) {
    for( var i=0, len=usersContacts.length; i<len; i++ ){
        if( usersContacts[i].name == item.name ) {
            usersContacts[i]['selectedContact'] = true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sending a HTTP DELETE request to the URL of a node should delete the node. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Well establishing the proper uri to delete the right node.

Comment: Ah, not I see it. `scope.contact.name` is likely not the same as the key of the node. Is your question how to look up the key of the node given `scope.contact.name`?

Comment: Yeah well to give more context I parsed the Object, take a look at revised question.

Comment: You're converting the key+value pairs (`selectedContacts.data`) that you get from Firebase into an array of just the values. Then later you need the key to delete the item. Wouldn't it be an option to not drop the key to begin with?

Comment: In addition: did you consider using the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/) or (even better) [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/)? These are made to solve many of the difficulties in mapping Firebase data to AngularJS.

Comment: LOL I actually have angularfire, there are just so many methods to pick from I naturally was more comfortable with the REST api. Good idea man, now I guess with angularfire I can get properly formatted data I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a user by their name:

```
...firebaseio.com/contacts.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="Ind"&limitToFirst=1
```

*You'll have to add an index to your security rules:*

```
{
  "rules": {
    "contacts": {
      ".indexOn": ["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

With this index, the query will return an object like this:

```
{
  "-K7qAf6egBeg5l3e_Gjc": {
     "name": "Ind",
     "phonenumber": "(408) ***-***",
     "uid": "1"
  }
}
```

You can read the key from there and then execute a REST DELETE request against

```
...firebaseio.com/contacts/-K7qAf6egBeg5l3e_Gjc.json
```

But as discussed in the comments to your question, you can also use AngularFire to do the same.

Comment: Thanks this seems to solve the missing piece of the puzzle, I am able to grab the objects and compare to existing objects to see which contacts were the chosen contacts. Using your solution above to delete a node if the user deselects a contact. Great, but I think I possibly messed up something because I am testing using  a GET request and I received this `contacts.json?orderBy=%22name%22&equalTo=%22Tatiah%22&limitToFirst=1 400 (Bad Request)` so it parsed the `"` into `%22` not sure if I messed up something, or if its invalid, I will keep trying.

Comment: The raw request looks like `$http.get(Firebaseurl + '/contacts.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="'+scope.contact.name+'"&limitToFirst=1')`

Comment: Oh I have to index the data! I had no clue, must have missed it, but it seems like it quite important the Docs should mention it more clearly. My fault though, it's just that there is information overload on the Firebase docs, but I mean there is a lot of stuff they offer so I cant really complain to much.